# Immutable Class how to tell

Tags: java, class, immutability

I understand that immutable means that it is an object that will not change state after it is instantiated. But in this line of code I dont see Final when the array values is declared.
Is this class immutable? Can anyone explain how to find out. Thanks

```
public class A {
private double[] values;
public double[] getValues(){
return values;
 }
}
```

Comment: See Implementation of String class in java. Best example for immutable class. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java

Comment: `final` wouldn't actually help here; it's returning the immutable array without a copy that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As other have written this object is considered to be mutable in its state. What it is immutable to is that you can not exchange the array it holds. But you can change the array's content (getValues()[0] = 10;).

To convert this to a immutable object you must use List instead of an array. With List you can use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)' method [unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to convert a given list into a version you can savely expose to the outside. If the caller of getValues() uses add or remove on a unmodifiable list it will result into a UnsupportedOpertionException keeping your object save from being modified.

If you need to stick to arrays you need to provide a copy (System.arraycopy) or a clone (clone()) of the array.

Usually a object is considered to be immutable if you can not change its properties (including inherited properties from superclasses. This usually includes the properties values as well but this is a blurred definition.

For example if you have a class that holds a File instance which points to document file and this File instance can not be changed the class is considered to be immutable (the inforamtion it provides never changes) but the document it points to can be mutated and changed every time. So its a blurred line actually (remember in your example you can not change the array but the content of the array).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code pasted is not having any final keyword associated and has no immutable behavior.

Well i would like to bring forth some key guidelines related to writing immutable classes in java :

1.) Ensure the class cannot be overridden - make the class final, or use static factories and keep constructors private

2.) Make fields private and final
force callers to construct an object completely in a single step, instead of using a no-argument constructor combined with subsequent calls to setXXX methods (that is, avoid the Java Beans convention)

3.) Do not provide any methods which can change the state of the object in any way - not just setXXX methods, but any method which can change state

4.) If the class has any mutable object fields, then they must be defensively copied when they pass between the class and its caller

Comment: What modifier should you use on an attribute of a public class so that the
attribute (or method) can be accessed from subclasses of the class in any package but
cannot be accessed from other classes in different packages? Would this be the default?

Comment: @Juan protected. The default modifier allows any class in the same package to access it. protected is subclasses. Although, after giving your post a second read it sounds like you want some kind of hybrid between the two...

Comment: @Cruncher - `protected` allows access by subclasses in any package _and also_ by any code in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = new A();
a.getValues()[0] = 1.2;
```

This would work as long as values is not empty. You will however not be able to reassign values to a new array. That is: `a.getValues() = new double[5];` will not work.

The class is not immutable, as I can change values, just not reassign it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple verification. the values are initialized to 1,2.

Using the getter and a reference, one is able to change the values inside the first item in the array after the object is created

```
public class A {
    private double[] values;

    public double[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A test = new A();
        test.values= new double[]{1, 2};

        double[] valuesref = test.getValues();
        valuesref[0] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.values.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(test.values[i]);    
        }
    }
}
```

This can be avoided if getValues() returns a copy of the array.

Comment: This is kind of cheating since `test.values=` would not work from any other class. But I think this demonstrates the point anyway

Comment: Right, there is very limited use of such a class which doesnt have setters or a non default constructor. Just wanted to highlight the fact that arrays can have their values changed using reference